# How do I split up a django project into seperate already created applications?

Tags: django, git

I have a Django project with some applications from the directories of some github repositories. I've made some changes into them and would like to push the changes to my forks of the projects. The project directory looks like this:

```
mainproject
--foo
--bar
```

where foo and bar are two directories of different github repositories. The mainproject is itself a git repository. The repository containing foo looks like this:

```
project
--foo
--someotherfolder
```

Ideally I'd like to keep the applications within the mainproject folder.

Answer (score 2):

The way I manage this in my project is using git submodules.

I have a dependencies folder (in my main project app) where I track all my dependencies i.e. Third party django apps.

You will need to do

git submodule add /foo.git /foo
git submodule add /bar.git /bar

You may find this link helpful. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules